# UE：How to use StereoLayer on Hololens2？

Tags: unreal-engine4, hololens, mrtk, unreal-engine5, openxr

MRTK + OpenXR + UE4

https://docs.unrealengine.com/5.1/en-US/openxr-stero-layers-overview-in-unreal-engine/

I used StereoLayer, but found it didn’t work on Hololens2. How should it be set?

I want to render different textures for the left and right eyes（Camera）in UE hololens2

Comment: I did some tests according to https://docs.unrealengine.com/5.1/en-US/openxr-stereo-layers-quick-start-in-unreal-engine/, StereoLayers is available on HoloLens 2. How did you set it up? Is there any error message returned?
Regarding rendering different textures for left and right eyes, is the description in https://docs.unrealengine.com/5.1/en-US/stereoscopic-rendering-with-ndisplay-in-unreal-engine/ what you want? If not, please describe your scenario in detail.

Comment: @ZuochengWang-MSFT Does hololens 2 use nDisplay? My application followed this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unreal/tutorials/unreal-uxt-ch1, and was packaged as a UWP application and uploaded to Hololens 2 to run. The StereoLayer did not render

Comment: Have you tried to create a new project to test this feature? Can you provide some screenshots or steps? It should be noted that the texture used in the Unreal documentation won't look as good on HoloLens 2, you can use a brighter texture instead. And you can set the Location.X of the Stereo Layer to 200 to get a better experience.